# Creating mod_rewrite rule with GET variable

Tags: mod-rewrite, get

can anybody help me to create a mod_rewrite rule? please...

Default URL= http://domain.com/check.php?host=google.com

With mod_rewrite= http://domain.com/google.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

#Skip existent dirs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Skip existent files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Rewrite /foo to /check.php?host=foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /check.php?host=$1 [NC,L]
```